# My wordpress website displays only the homepage

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I have created an additional pages for my portfolio yet the permalink on the site only links to my homepage. Any time I even want to preview one of my other pages (unpublished or published), it takes me to the same homepage. Any advice?

Comment: As a guess and only a guess, check to make sure your wp_blogs or wp_site rows are correct, check your values in wp-config.php if you have these [swap DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE for your domain
```define('WPSITEURL','http://' . DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE);
    define('WPHOME','http://' . DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE);
    define('WP_SITEURL','http://' . DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE);
    define('WP_HOME','http://' . DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE);```
And dbl dbl check you have your htaccess set up if using apache

Comment: Visit Settings > Permalinks in your dashboard. That usually clears this up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check permalink settings.
There are several ways to use links in wordpress.
You can find permalink setting on admin dashboard/settings/permalink.
If you can't get any improved, I recommend that you 'd rather check console in developer mode on your browser, fix all the errors.